# Layer states of NetBidirectionalOperator

Tags: neural-networks

I want to define a `NetBidirectionalOperator` version of this network, how do I access states of forward and backward net with `NetPort`?

```
NetGraph[<|
  "rnn" -> GatedRecurrentLayer[32, "Input" -> {"Varying", 32}],
  "state_net" -> NetChain[{LinearLayer[32, "Input" -> 32]}]|>,
 {NetPort["StateInput"] -> "state_net" -> NetPort["rnn", "State"],
  NetPort["Input"] -> "rnn"}]
```